# One character messes up htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp

I'm using Ubuntu 12 server with LAMP (installed everything today and made a full upgrade) and I'm using the following .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^messages/received/?$ messages.php?p=received [L]
```

And I'm getting a "Not Found" page when I go to `http://localhost/messages/received/`

Now the strange thing is that if I remove the final 's' of 'messages' :

```
RewriteRule ^message/received/?$ messages.php?p=received [L]
```

then it works perfectly.

Using the same file on my Mac with MAMP raises no error.

Update : Apparently this is because I have a file "(www_root)/messages/received.php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update : Apparently this is because I have a file "(www_root)/messages/received.php".

This sounds like multiviews (mod_negotiation) is doing this. In your options directive, try adding `-Multiviews`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
```